# What is the latest ASP .NET MVC version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I was trying to check the latest ASP MVC version, but I got really confused. I was able to understand the problem that happened first when Microsoft declared MVC 5 and then renamed it to MVC Core 1.0.

Still I see now in Microsoft documentation for the regular .NET framework they only mention MVC version 5 as the latest version, while on the web everywhere I would find topics about what is new in MVC 6.0, which has the famous feature of removing dependency over System.Web. Also 6.0 is mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC) with release date for rc1 as 18 Nov 2015

So is it called MVC 6 by Microsoft or still they call it 5? what is the latest dlls versions for MVC?

Comment: There is asp.net-mvc-5.2.3 which is last version before they went to asp.net-core-mvc. Web API 2.2 also shares the 5.2.3 version number. Check Nuget

Comment: check this out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC ... it mentions MVC 6.0 which is strange. Maybe Microsoft changed the name

Comment: 6 eventually became core. There was this  whole back and forth where 5 was to be developed in parallel to the vNext but that got scrapped. There is no MVC 6.0 . All mention of it just has not been corrected as yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109524/what-is-the-difference-between-asp-net-mvc-6-and-asp-net-core-1-0-and-the-reason

Comment: Well I thought that confusion was about 5.0. check this blog by Scott Hanselman http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/2101133.aspx?What+is+the+difference+between+MVC6+and+ASP+net+Core+

Comment: I know. I was in the middle of all that when it was happening. Trying to be on the bleeding edge. MVC6 became core because of the rewrite.

Comment: I see. well thank you this makes sense now, although Microsoft should have better explained this on ASP site at least. I was completely lost

Comment: It was a PR nightmare that caused a lot of confusion when it happened. They try not talk about it (PTSD) in hope that people forget that it ever happened. lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148170/discussion-between-a-khudairy-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is asp.net-mvc-5.2.3 which is last version before they went to asp.net-core-mvc. Web API 2.2 also shares the 5.2.3 version number. Check Nuget

MVC 6 was originally part of ASP.NET 5 and suppose to be the next version, but due to major changes in the code base, it was decided that it needed to become its own new framework, they decided to change its name from ASP.NET 5 to [ASP.NET Core.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) which is the suggested latest version to use going forward for new projects.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I believe currently the asp-core is a completely separate path, so there will be new versions for the regular path, maybe we will see 5.3 soon (I have not checked their official announcements though)

Comment: @AKhudairy, They have agreed to maintain and patch it for the time being but no new development is expected to be forthcoming. They want people moving over to core. I still do the brunt of my dev on 5 while keeping up to date on core. Waiting for it to settle before crossing over completely.

Answer (score -1):

ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1.1 released on 14 January 2020 is the latest ASP.NET MVC version. Post-release of ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 on 29 November 2018, Microsoft decided to release the next version (with major changes) under the ASP.NET Core MVC category.