# View Component in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-framework-version, view-components

I can't find any examples for implementing a View Component in ASP.NET MVC Framework 4.5. I love to work with them in .NET Core, but it's really hard to find if they exist in ASP.NET MVC Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as ViewComponent in ASP.NET MVC in .NET Framework 4.5 or later versions. Or even on ASP.NET MVC 5 or later versions.

These ViewComponents exist on ASP.NET Core technologies which were previously called ASP.NET MVC 6.

You can check the list of versions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC

And also related reference: [What is the difference between ASP.NET MVC 6 and ASP.NET Core 1.0 and the reason behind the core framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109524/what-is-the-difference-between-asp-net-mvc-6-and-asp-net-core-1-0-and-the-reason)